# Use a fixed point argument to show there exists a unique solution to the following BVP

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification, banach-spaces, fixed-point-theorems

Show using a fixed point argument that there exists a unique solution $f\in C[0,1]$ to

$$ -f''(x)+\sin(f(x))=\sin(x) , x\in (0,1), y(0)=y'(1)=0 $$

This is what I have so far:

We can show separately that the Green's function for $-f''$ is $g(x,y)=\min(x,y)$.  So let's use

$$ -\min(x,y)f''(x)+\min(x,y)\sin(f(x))=\min(x,y)\sin(x)$$

Integrating with respect to $x$, this becomes

$$ f(y)+ \int^1_0 \min(x,y)\sin(f(x))\,dx=\int^1_0 \min(x,y)\sin(x)\,dx $$

So if we consider an operator $Tf=\int^1_0 \min(x,y)\sin(x)\,dx-\int^1_0 \min(x,y),sin(f(x))\,dx$, we determine if it a contraction map

$$Tf(y)-Tg(y)= -\int^1_0 \min(x,y)(\sin(f(x))-sin(g(x)))\,dx$$

Using a trig identity,

$$Tf(y)-Tg(y)= -\int^1_0 2\min(x,y)\sin((f-g)/2)\cos((f+g)/2)\,dx $$

or

$$Tf-Tg= -2\int^y_0 x\sin((f-g)/2)\cos((f+g)/2)\,dx-2y\int^1_y \sin((f-g)/2)\cos((f+g)/2)\,dx $$

How do I proceed to get $\|Tf-Tg\| < C \|f-g\|$ with $C<1$? Hints?

Comment: LaTeX hint: putting a \ before your sines, cosines, and mins make them look better.